# SQL Server Express 2005 SP3 Update Keeps Coming Back (KB995706)

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, windows-update

I have installed the above update through Windows Update. The update went through, reported a successful installation, and then straight after that it came back as an available update.

I have done it a few times and my update log now contains multiple successful installations of KB995706.

I have tried to uncheck it in the list of updates but it keeps coming back as well.

The machine is a Server 2008 RC2 Standard. It's got SQL Server 2005 Express as well as SQL Server 2008 Standard.

In the Event Log:

> Installation Successful: Windows
>   successfully installed the following
>   update: Microsoft SQL Server 2005
>   Express Edition Service Pack 3
>   (KB955706)

followed by

> Installation Ready: The following
>   updates are downloaded and ready for
>   installation. To install the updates,
>   an administrator should log on to this
>   computer and Windows will prompt with
>   further instructions: 
>   - Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Service Pack 3 (KB955706)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any Hot-fixes on this server? Those can block subsequent updates. Check the Add/Remove control panel.

Comment: Yes, there are several hotfixes for Visual Studio 2008 and two Windows hotfixes (KB976422 and KB975467). No hotfix for SQL Server though.

Comment: I'd wager *one* of those is blocking SP3. However, I'm not sure of the best way to figure out the blocker (short of uninstalling the hot-fixes, installing SP3 and then trying to get the hot-fixes re-installed...